# Weight force or gravitational force?

Tags: limits, trigonometry, physics, mathematical-physics, education

Taking the case of a hydrogen atom with the relative masses of proton and electron the electrical interaction (module) $F^C$ is much more intense than the gravitational interaction (module) $F^G$ (on a microscopic scale): the gravitation must be seen as a very weak interaction. Therefore the gravitation is seen as a very weak interaction:

$$\frac{F^G}{F^C}\approx 4.4 \cdot 10^{-40}$$

If $1$ and $2$ are two identical spheres of mass $m$, associated to the same electric charge $q$, (see the image in Italian language),

[image]

are in equilibrium suspended from two wires of length $\ell$,

---

*Fig. 1*

[image]

if $$m=\frac{k_0q^2\cos(\alpha)}{4\ell^2 g\sin^3(\alpha)} \tag 1$$

> *My question are*:
>
> 1. is it a real case if the system of charges is in equilibrium considering that the gravitational force $\mathbf{F}^G$ equilibrate the electrostatic force $\mathbf{F}^C$ (to see the colored vectors in the *figure 1.*)?
> 2. If $\alpha \to 0$ then $m\to \infty$. Is it possible to consider physically this case, and what can I write?

---

**Proof of the $(1)$ (out of the question for my students of an high school)**:

If I consider the gravitational force I have found that:

$$m=\frac{k_0q^2}{4\ell^2 g\sin^2(\alpha)} \tag2$$

where $F^G=F^C \iff Gm^2=k_0q^2$ with $g=Gm/(2r)^2$. Hence $g\cdot 4r^2=Gm$ and $m(g\cdot 4r^2)=k_0q^2$; after I will have, being $r=\ell \sin(\alpha)$,

$$m=\frac{k_0q^2}{4gr^2}=\frac{k_0q^2}{4g\ell^2\sin^2(\alpha)}$$

Being $(1)\neq (2)$, I have taken the weight-force $\mathbf{P}$ instead of the gravitational force $\mathbf{F}^G$ like this figure:

*Fig. 2*

[image]

where

\begin{cases}
T_y-mg=0 \iff & T_y=P=mg\\
T_x-F^C=0 \iff & T_x=F^C
\end{cases}

After
$$\tan(\alpha)=\frac{T_x}{T_y}=\frac{F^C}{mg}=\frac{\frac{k_0q^2}{4r^2}}{mg} \iff m=\frac{k_0q^2}{4gr^2\tan(\alpha)}=\frac{k_0q^2\cos(\alpha)}{4\ell^2 g\sin^3(\alpha)}$$
rembering that $r=\ell \sin\alpha$.

Comment: Well, the problem asks to find $m$ knowing that the two spheres are in equilibrium and you got it. I don't really understand the first question, what do you mean by "is it a real case"? About the second question, the limit can be interpreted as follows: As the angle $\alpha$ reduces to zero, also the projection $\tan\alpha\rightarrow0$, so to have $P(\alpha)\tan\alpha=F^C=constant$, you need $P(\alpha)=gm(\alpha)\rightarrow\infty$, that is, bigger and bigger mass, so that the growth of $P(\alpha)$ compensate for the reduction of $\tan\alpha$, resulting in the constant value $F^C$.

Comment: @Alessandro Hi Alessandro from Sicily. The expression: *"is it a real case"* is equivalent *does is it a pratical, or concrete case, that this event exists?* Please, can you convert with others complete explanation, your comment in an answer? I have not understood what is  $P(\alpha)$. Thank you very much.

Comment: 1. Regardless the analytical resolution, yes, this is a real system that you can easily build in the lab. I wonder why you are asking. 2. You can't deploy infinite masses, can you ? In any case, increasing the mass, at some point the balls will touch.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Hi, I'm asking this question for many doubts in my mind :-)...I'm very tired and I have given this information to my students. Please, can you put an image with an answer. My English level is very poor, also if I write, now without the translator. I understand better with the answers than with the comments.

Comment: @Sebastiano: mi dispiace, ma no.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Very good for the Italian language :-)

Comment: @YvesDaoust Hi, for your humble opinion is there a reason for a recent downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the case is very. Actually, the whole point of the exercise is to find for what mass $m$ of the two spheres so that at the system at equilibrium present the configuration in the picture. So, this case exists if you give a charge $q$ to a sphere (and also $q$ to the other), suspended by wires of length $\ell$, both spheres of mass $$\frac{k_0q^2\cos \alpha}{4\ell^2 g\sin^3\alpha}$$

As for the **second question**, the idea is that if you don't change $q$, then $F^C$ (the repulsive Coulombian force) is constant. The limit $\alpha\rightarrow0$ means that the two spheres are getting closed, so its either because a third force is applied moving the two spheres closed, or because the gravitational force $P=mg$ is increasing (so as the mass increases, it prevail over the force $F^C$, drawing the spheres together). The reason is that at the equilibrium $$gm\tan\alpha=F^C=c=\text{constant}\rightarrow m=\frac{c}{g\tan \alpha}$$ so as $\alpha\rightarrow0$, then factor $\tan\alpha$ converges to zero, so $gm$ must diverge to $\infty$ so that $gm\tan\alpha$ is the constant value $c$.

Comment: Thank you, in the meantime, for your precious collaboration.

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: ...welcome also for me :-)

Comment: the charges should be equal, not opposite.

Comment: yes @user, you're right. I'll correct it

Comment: @Alessandro Excuse me very much for my delay to put the green check mark.

Comment: @Sebastiano, no problem